# I need to delete specif word in text file form each line

Tags: text, cpu-word, aspell

I have text file with words like below.

```
motať sa
živiť sa
sabotovať
baviť sa
nasavať
```

And I want to delete word sa wrom each line. But I won't delete "sa" from word "sabotovať" or "nasavať". 
My final result will look like this:

```
motať
živiť
sabotovať
baviť
nasavať
```

I need this for ASPELL because ASPELL takes empty gap between words that "sa" is new word.
I am using WINDOWS. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a programming language you would like to use?  Or just built in windows command line tools?

Comment: Command line tools. But I need also to delete word with intepunction like "budeš".

Answer (score 0):

You can (should) get `sed` from cygwin or other unix toolsets for your windows system(s)

To remove the word at the end of the line

```
sed 's/ sa$//' inputFile > outputFile
```

New question from comments (to remove a specific word)

```
sed 's/budeš//' inputFile > outputFile
```

Another new question from comments (to remove a word within a line - including at EOL)

```
sed 's/ sa//' inputFile > outputFile
```

Comment: And if i want delete word "budeš"? It don't work. How to do it?

Comment: #1 - you're welcome, feel free to upvote/accept - #2 - to delete the word you wish, just include it in place of the ' sa'

Comment: I know, but it don't work. And I also have word like "bude sa robiť" and "sa" from here don't disapear after your command.

Comment: Regex are very specific and so I solved only for the stated problem.  If you change (correctly expand) the problem statement, then the solution will be better.  My advice (after this edit) will be to apply my solution and then read up on regex - the things you want to do are simple - but regex can be VERY complex.

Comment: If you are going down the regex path like @KevinDTimm said, then check out: http://www.regexper.com  It is a great tool to help you build regular expressions.